# Click Button to activate EventListener to get only next key pressed

Tags: java, javafx, keylistener

I am making a Tetris clone with JavaFX, and what I am "trying to do is allow the user to configure custom key bindings for specific actions." I am not using a FXML file or controllers; I am using Java JDK 8.

I am making a "Set Custom Controls" menu, using `Stage` and `Scene`. I want to list all the different controls in `Labels` with a `Button` next to each.

When the user clicks a `Button`, I want that to activate an `EventListener<KeyEvent>` to grab just the first key pressed after clicking that Button in order to assign that `KeyCode` to the corresponding `KeyCode class variable.

Also, if the user decides they made a mistake clicking the Button, I want to allow them to click the `Button` again to cancel the `EventListener<KeyEvent>`.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How to make clicking inside a TextBox activate a KeyListener to grab just the next key pressed.

Comment: Do you mean TextField?

Comment: This just sounds like *completely* the wrong approach to whatever it is you’re trying to do. You should never use a key listener with a text input control.

Comment: I should use a Button instead of a TextField, but what I'm trying to accomplish is what I have seen in nearly every PC game I've ever played. In the controls menu, it lists the different controls with the current key assigned to each control. When you click that control's Button, it takes whatever key you press next and assigns it to that control. A KeyListener is the only thing I can think of, but if you have a different approach, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is allow the user to configure custom key bindings for specific actions. Is that correct?

Comment: @Slaw that is correct

Comment: Maybe you want an [accelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710468/using-javafx-2-2-mnemonic-and-accelerators/12714730#12714730), but that is just for delegating the key presses to controls, not necessary for dynamically changing the keys which will access a control.  I don't have a suggestion for you for recording key combinations to assign to accelerators.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I added EventHandler<KeyEvent> handlers in start(). When a user clicks the Button for the corresponding control, that event handler is added from inside start(). When the user hits a key, it assigns the key and then removes the EventHandler<KeyEvent>. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can answer your own question.  Well, at least you could if it wasn’t closed, perhaps next time :-)

Comment: @jewelsea: I'd like to offer a different approach; voting to reopen.

Comment: I think it needs one or two more votes to be reopened.

Comment: I edited the title and text. Hoping it will be reopened upon review. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73114862/click-button-to-activate-eventlistenerkeyevent-to-get-only-next-key-pressed#comment129133960_73114862) by @Slaw, you want to "allow the user to configure custom key bindings for specific actions." One [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73114862/click-button-to-activate-eventlistenerkeyevent-to-get-only-next-key-pressed#comment129134100_73115508) would be "a key-event editor for JavaFX like the one cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6366456/230513) for Swing."

The example below focuses narrowly on capturing raw key presses. As suggested [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm#JFXED117), a `KeyEvent` listener captures the user's keystroke, displaying the name of the game event and updating the pressed key code's name. `KeyCode.TAB` is reserved for navigation, and the rest are consumed. The resulting key event and game event are stored in a `Map` for later reference. As @James_D [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73114862/click-button-to-activate-eventlistener-to-get-only-next-key-pressed/73130018#comment129133402_73114862), typical usage would "never use a key listener with a text input control." In this case, the focused, but non-editable `TextField` conveniently displays the pressed key's name.

[image]

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73130018/230513 */
public class KeyCodeSelector extends Application {

    private final Map<KeyEvent, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(createKeyPane("Left: ", KeyCode.LEFT));
        root.getChildren().add(createKeyPane("Right: ", KeyCode.RIGHT));
        var scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private Pane createKeyPane(String s, KeyCode k) {
        var label = new Label(s);
        label.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);
        label.setMinWidth(50);
        var textField = new TextField(k.getName());
        label.setLabelFor(textField);
        textField.setEditable(false);
        textField.setOnKeyPressed((keyEvent) -> {
            var keyCode = keyEvent.getCode();
            if (keyCode != KeyCode.TAB) {
                textField.setText(keyCode.getName());
                map.put(keyEvent, s);
                keyEvent.consume();
            }
        });
        var grid = new GridPane();
        grid.add(label, 0, 0);
        grid.add(textField, 0, 1);
        return new HBox(label, textField);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great. I was having trouble figuring out how to word my question, because I didn't really know how to implement what I wanted. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

I will share my solution for anyone who runs into problem. I will use my implementation for setting the key binding for moving a block left.

I created the class variables:

```java
private Scene sceneControlOptions;
private EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyHandlerBtnMoveLeft;
private Button btnMoveLeft;
private KeyCode controlButtonMoveLeft;
```

Inside the method to create and display my control options menu (Stage and Scene):

```java
btnMoveLeft.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            btnMoveLeft.setText("---");
            sceneControlOptions.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyHandlerBtnMoveLeft);
        });
```

And finally, inside of start() I added:

```java
keyHandlerBtnMoveLeft = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                KeyCode key = event.getCode();
                setControlButtonMoveLeft(key);
                btnMoveLeft.setText(key.getName().toString());
                sceneControlOptions.removeEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyHandlerBtnMoveLeft);
            }
        };
```

Where setControlButtonMoveLeft(key) is:

```java
private void setControlButtonMoveLeft(KeyCode key) {
    this.controlButtonMoveLeft = key;
}
```