# How can I remap certain keys?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, jtextfield, documentfilter

I want to create a virtual numeric keyboard, so that when I press **U** I get a **4**, **I** produces a **5**, **O** produces a **6**, and so on:

```
789            789
uio   becomes  456  
jkl            123
m              0
```

But I need the rest of the keyboard to continue working as usual. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6366044/1716488) and some other solutions, but they are not useful to me, because on my JTextField I get **`4U5I6O`** (or **`U4I5O6`** depending on which solution I implement).

I need to get rid of the letter, and produce only the number.

Does anybody know a proper solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't your keyboard event handler single out your letters, and act on them as if the number had been pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are typing directly to [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html), then I recommend to use [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html).

As an example of [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html), see:

- [Only allowing numbers and a symbol (-) to be typed into a JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8017847/597657)

Comment: I tried the suggested solution, but the methods in the filter are never invoked, and thus, I get the original letters in my text.

Comment: @ilvidel Did you set the filter with `setDocumentFilter()`?

Comment: @ilvidel If you tried this, post an SSCCE of this in your question. This approach should work, so most likely you are doing something wrong

Comment: @Eng.Fouad (and Robin) Ok, I was obviously doing something wrong. I did use  `setDocumentFilter()` but I must have missed something else. Today, with a fresh mind I did it all over, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an eample of @Eng.Fouad's suggestion (please, all credit to him).

Basically, this will replace all the text entered into the text field with a random character instead.

I wouldn't be difficult to update the code to deliver mapped changes (for example `a = 1`) or even an encryption process.

```
public class TestPhasicDocumentFilter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPhasicDocumentFilter();
    }

    public TestPhasicDocumentFilter() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new PhasicPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PhasicPane extends JPanel {

        public PhasicPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JTextField field = new JTextField(12);
            add(field);

            ((AbstractDocument)field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new PhasicDocumentFilter());

        }

        public class PhasicDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {
            protected String phasic(String text) {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
                for (int index = 0; index < sb.length(); index++) {
                    sb.setCharAt(index, (char)(33 + (int)Math.round(Math.random() * 93)));
                }

                return sb.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, phasic(text), attr);
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, phasic(text), attrs);
            }

        }

    }

}
```